# Best practice of building own Django 'push'?

Tags: django, push

I have a working, but really inefficient solution to a turn based game related problem.

I'd now like to optimize it.

Short version:
Two players share a pretty much identical view of the game's board, with the exception that the active player is able to 'play' and the inactive player only can view the board.

The active player is shown a view with several buttons to interact with the board, and the inactive is instead shown a short 'wait for you'r turn'-message.
These templates are loaded into a div, using JQuery's .load()-method.

However, there is 0-3 moves in each turn, and every one of these moves are to be displayed 'live' to both players.

As of now, i have a javascript timer that **each second** reloads:

**A)** A hidden div, holding only a 'move' and 'turn' variable fetched from the game's model. (which in terms of data traffic is > 10 bytes)
If there are changes made during a move ->

**B)** Reload the board-view.
if a player is satisfied using less then 3 moves - there is a 'pass turn'-option, or uses all 3 moves ->

**C)** Resets the move variable to 0 and changes the active player. (Displaying different views, mentioned above)

I'm aware that server calls each second is a really awful way of practice and really need some input.

Answer (score 0):

Check out websockets, this would allow you to "push" updates to the client browsers.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

And for a specific django module:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-websocket

Comment: Great, i'll look into it. Just knew there had to be a better way. Thanks.